# MySQL multiple selects on second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I am trying to construct a select statement. The table structure is shown below. I am basically looking to select the three fields on the left table along with the meta_values of the right hand side table that have a meta_key of responsible_service and responsible_officer. These meta_values may or may not exist.

My awful attempt looks like this.

```
SELECT 
 `wp_posts`.`ID`,
`wp_posts`.`post_content`,
`wp_posts`.`post_title`
FROM(
`wp_posts`
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON (`wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`),
(Select `wp_postmeta`.meta_value where`wp_postmeta`.meta_key='responsible_officer') as Responsible Officer),
(Select `wp_postmeta`.meta_value where `wp_postmeta`.meta_key='responsible_service') as Responsible Service ),
```

[image]

The result should look like this

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the result that you want.  Your query is not 100% clear.

Comment: use left outer join add condition in ON clause

Comment: Your query doesn't end. It just...

Comment: I have added the result I am looking for in the image, the answer I accepted wasn't completely correct. Still need help.

Comment: can you explain what's the issue you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you 1 or more rows per `wp_posts`.`ID` depending on how many 'responsible_officer' and 'responsible_service' are found. If none are found meta_key and meta_value will be `null`

```
SELECT 
 `wp_posts`.`ID`,
`wp_posts`.`post_content`,
`wp_posts`.`post_title`,
 max(case `wp_postmeta`.meta_key
   when 'responsible_officer' then `wp_postmeta`.meta_value end) as responsible_officer,
 max(case `wp_postmeta`.meta_key
   when 'responsible_service' then `wp_postmeta`.meta_value end) as responsible_service
FROM
`wp_posts`
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`
                        AND `wp_postmeta`.meta_key in ('responsible_officer', 'responsible_service')

   group by `wp_posts`.`ID`,
    `wp_posts`.`post_content`,
    `wp_posts`.`post_title`;
```

Comment: I have updated the image to show that I want 'responsible_officer' and 'responsible_service' selected as separate entities, does this make sense?

Comment: @killie Yes, with CASE and group by. So just zero or one reponsible officer and zero or one responsible_service per ID?

Comment: @killie ups, an extra comma. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Check this also:

```
select postmeta.meta_value, posts.ID, posts.`post_content`,
posts.`post_title` from `wp_posts` posts join `wp_postmeta` postmeta on posts.ID = postmeta.post_id where postmeta.meta_key IN ('responsible_officer', 'responsible_service')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 `wp_posts`.`ID`,
`wp_posts`.`post_content`,
`wp_posts`.`post_title`
FROM `wp_posts`
JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON (`wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`)
where `wp_postmeta`.meta_key in ('responsible_officer', 'responsible_service')
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.